Best way to clone Wordpress website for testing environment (subdomain)
I want to have a testing environment for my Wordpress website and I was wondering what the best option would be, as there are many I guess. I've seen many guides with cPanel, which I'm not using though.
Can I just manually copy the website to a new directory, name it like my subdomain-name, change the url in the config and be good to go?

No - Wordpress relies heavily on the MySQL database. Running 2 instances off the same dataset would result in unpredictable results. Also the site name is baked into both the configuration and the data. Export and import the database:
mysqladmin create database clonedb
mysqlbackup originaldb | mysql clonedb

Then run these updates (changing the URL as appropriate) in the clonedb
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'https://example.com/clone' WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl', 'home');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'example.com/original', 'example.com/clone')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%example.com/original%';

Depending on what plugins you have there may be other tables requiring updates.
Copy the files to a new directory, configure the site in Apache, create a database user with permissions to read/write the new DB and update the config.php in the new site.
Turn on Wordpress debugging for the new site (if its not already on) and test it out.

Alright, thank you for your detailed answer. I'm using Uberspace as a hosting service, which seems to be a bit special and different than traditional ones. I'll try it out!
